# Oracle sql change (dynamic) column order

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I know the column order can be changed from the order they're selected. My problem is a little bit more involved so please ask in the comments if you do not understand my question.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT NVL(status, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS row_labels
      ,NVL(order_source, 'GRAND TOTAL2') AS order_source
      ,count(1) Count#
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (status), CUBE(order_source)
order by case
        when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END;
```

For simplicity, I am saying "SOMETABLE", that clause is also quite involved.

Here is the data from above query:

[image]

I create a view out of this and use the view in another function as below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(
pivot('SELECT * FROM TEST1')
);
```

Here is the data after the pivot:

[image]

Here are the two problems:

1. I would like that Grand Total2 to be the last column similar to how the Grand Total is the last row.
2. I would also like the 'Grand Total2' label as 'GRAND TOTAL' as well, but when I change this label to 'GRAND TOTAL' in my select query, I get lots of null, below is the data. Please notice the GRAND TOTAL2 column. The label does not change at all.

Just to be clear, this is what I am creating a view out of for number 2 above:

```
SELECT NVL(status, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS row_labels
      ,NVL(order_source, 'GRAND TOTAL') AS order_source
      ,count(1) Count#
FROM
SOMETABLE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (status), CUBE(order_source)
order by case
        when status = 'GRAND TOTAL' THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END;
```

[image]

The source of the pivot function is located here: http://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was just thinking that I think I might have to work on my Order by clause. How can I make it such that the Grand Total and Grand Total2 are in the bottom?

Comment: So I was able to bring GT2 at the bottom by ordering by desc. But that did not change the column order in the pivot function.

Comment: I also got the label to change as Grand Total with out the 2. The creation on View was playing tricks. Now changing the labels name is consistent, I do not get unnecessary nulls.

Comment: The pivot function seems to be oredering the columns in ascending order. If I change the label to "Z", then this column is the last column.

Comment: don't use pivot. Use a traditional `group by` query where the columns are MAX(case when expression then field). This gives you full control over the columns sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar challenge with data that I wanted to be in `member1_id` going to `member2_id` and vise versa.

I resulted to using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_id)` instead of using the ORDER BY clause at the end of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY order_id) order_col, col1, col2 ...
)
PIVOT (
    MAX(col1) id, MAX(col2) name, ...
    FOR order_col IN (1 col1, 2 col2, ...)
);
```